Cannot partition using Ubuntu MATE installer
I have a Toshiba Satellite c50d-b 4 GB RAM, 500GB hard drive. I want to install Ubuntu MATE 24.04 alongside Windows 10, but I cannot format or resize the Windows 10 partition. In the installation menu as seen in the screen photo it is the Next option is gray (inactive). In the BIOS I have replaced UEFI boot with CSM Boot, and I have disabled Fast
Boot. Do you have any ideas how to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10?


You picture (when present in your question) was difficult to read & didn't include all detail; but I could see the maximum number of partitions for a legacy or MBR type partition table already existed (thus you couldn't add more!), so what type of partition table are you using?  (you're at maximum for legacy boot; but not GPT) .  You also provided no release details (Ubuntu MATE uses different installers based on release & you provided no specifics)

Use Windows partition manager to shrink the C drive

It looks like you have gpt, Microsoft requires gpt for UEFI boot. And Microsoft requires MBR(msdos) for BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot. So which do you have. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012. If gpt, you need to always boot in UEFI mode, not legacy. How you choose to boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. But then setting in UEFI/BIOS for UEFI or Legacy determines how installed system boots.

Hello, this is what gives me the sudo parted print command.                                  sudo parted  /dev/sda print
Model: ATA HGST HTS545050A7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt                                                                                                                     It's a gpt disk, what can I do to change it? Do I have to format?

If you're using a GPT  (GUID partition table) then you can create a large number of primary partitions & creating partitions is not your problem.  Your ubuntu-desktop-installer (24.04 installer) wants you to select a partition you want to install into  as / etc.. and will only allow NEXT once you've setup the required partitions (/ file-system for install into, ESP if using uEFI boot etc), with the NEXT not able to be selected (by design) UNTIL you've selected the required partitions for manual partitioning which you've opted to use (top of your display)

Where you are in will let you select a partition where you can then select CHANGE (lower left in your picture) to make changes to it

The ubuntu-desktop-installer (24.04 installer) does not work, I used gparted, which works fine, but even when I partition with gparted, the next button remains grayed out, so I can't install Ubuntu Mate.

The picture you've provided shows no required selected partitions that I can see, thus NEXT should be UNCLICKABLE as you've not yet selected the required mount points.  There is no linked partition in your picture for / as stated in my prior comment, nor ESP selected either (if required; that is machine specific as not all devices use ESP to boot, though its been required for windows 8+ devices; but Ubuntu will install on devices from the XP era which didn't require it)

I can't select a mount point on sda4 or resize or format, everything is grayed out or unclickable.

Select it and click the CHANGE button (which will allow you to tell the installer what you want to do with the partition).  You're using Manual Partitioning thus it's a more manual process (ie. you specify everything manually; its far slower but you have control).   If you look at your picture again, yes the NEXT is shadowed, but CHANGE is not; use it.  The main tutorial is https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview  where Ubuntu-MATE uses the same installer so other than some graphics (ie. it'll say Ubuntu-MATE instead of Ubuntu Desktop) its the same
